# Architecture Resources in Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-group

We are developing applications in .Net and deploying them to Azure app services. We currently have a multi-tier environment (QA/STG/PROD). In order to replicate the same environments we are using slots. However, the issue with slots is all developers who has access to QA slot are able to view/modify STG / PROD slot settings. We want to segregate this with authorization where-in users should only be able to publish apps on QA. Should we still use slots or we go with separate web apps?

Comment: You can set [role based access control](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/01/07/managing-user-access-to-specific-sites-in-the-azure-portal/) seperately to different slots. Click on that slot and click **Access control (IAM)**.

Comment: @forester123 You should elaborate your comment a bit more and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comments you can use RBAC (Role Based Access Control) to control the user permissions on the web app/slots.

[Azure RBAC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-what-is/#built-in-roles) has three basic roles that apply to all resource types:

- **Owner** has full access to all resources including the right to delegate access to others.
- **Contributor** can create and manage all types of Azure resources but can’t grant access to others.
- **Reader** can view existing Azure resources.

So, you could add the developers as a **READER** to the webapp and as a **CONTRIBUTOR** to one of the slots. This will prevent the web app changes

Further, you can customize the RBAC to suit your requirements. 
You can create a role with custom 
Refer this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-custom-roles/

Answer (score 0):

You can go with slots. Each slot creates a separate URL and you could control access to the slots by Authenticating using AD.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/

Comment: The way AAD authentication is set in the post is for authenticating users accessing the app and not for slots I guess.

Comment: When you create a slot, Azure creates an app with the Slot name in the URL. If you go to the "Deployment Slots" section in settings and click on the slot, it will open a new blade for this new app. It has its own URL and can be used to configure AAD Authentication.

Comment: Agreed. However, I am using the same AAD app for all slots to authenticate users. For this, I will have to configure different apps in AAD for different slots.

Comment: I don't know how you are doing this " I am using the same AAD app for all slots to authenticate users.". If you have multiple slots / web apps, you'll have to configure authentication for each as both will eventually create a separate URL. My suggestion is to create separate slots and authenticate each slot using AAD Authentication by creating groups of users for each slot.